# Angular UI Router ui-sref nesting

Tags: angularjs, routes, angular-ui-router, angularjs-routing

Currently building an online shop in angular. Structure is as follows

Store page - Category - Product

```
.state('shop', {
        url: '/shop'

.state('shop.category', {
        url: '/:slug'

.state('shop.category.product', {
        url: '/:slug'
```

I then use `<a ui-sref=".category({slug: cat.slug})">{{ foo }}</a>` to link from the shop page to the category page. this works fine. However how do I link from the category page to a product?

As you can imagine I want to keep the URL to look like this

> www.site.c@m/shop/dynamic-category/dynamic-product

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use, like `.product` will tell router that I want to go in child state & will pass slug value.

```
ui-sref=".product({slug: 'some-product'})"
```

But technically you should not have parameter `slug` in both child and parent state. because when you want to directly navigate to child state at that time whole thing will get messed up.

Like when you do `shop.category.product({slug: 'some-cat', slug: 'some-product'})` at that time you can have `slug` property in same json, javascript wouldn't get compile correctly.

So I'll suggest you have different name on each `state` for slug parameter like below

```
.state('shop', {
        url: '/shop'

.state('shop.category', {
        url: '/:catslug'

.state('shop.category.product', {
        url: '/:productslug'
```

Comment: You wouldnt know how I can link to a product from the homepage? I cant get the category paramater in the URL

Comment: See I had simplified state to have it accessible by anytime..I generally have that pattern..so that from anywhere I can redirect to that state.. But yes, you're correct. Somehow we should have catsslug and product available